# Ionic app linker errors after building for iOS

Tags: ios, xcode, ionic-framework, linker-errors

I am developing an app using the Ionic 4 framework and am currently attempting to build it for iOS and release it to the App Store. The error I am getting is when I attempt to run the app in Xcode, it will fail in the linking phase with the following error:

> ld: 346 duplicate symbols for architecture x86_64 clang: error: linker
>   command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation).

This is preceded by a list of the duplicate symbols like so:

> duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_FIRInstanceIDURLQueryItem._name in:
>       /Users/james/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Jambox-ataoinheliizvyaczvbklhkqvhpf/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/FirebaseInstanceID/libFirebaseInstanceID.a(FIRInstanceIDURLQueryItem.o)
>       Jambox/Plugins/cordova-plugin-firebase/FirebaseInstanceID.framework/FirebaseInstanceID(FIRInstanceIDURLQueryItem_ce817fff617a4255d51c2a25da32a1f0.o)

These are relating to the following frameworks:

- FirebaseInstanceID.framework
- GoogleUtilities.framework
- nanopb.framework
- FirebaseCore.framework

I have tried a few solutions to this problem, but none result in success:

1). Removing -ObjC and $(inherited) from Other Linker Flags - this causes the app to build and link successfully, but crash on startup with this error:

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '+[FIRApp
>   registerAsConfigurable:]: unrecognized selector sent to class
>   0x1080bc178'

2). Removing each framework in the list of duplicate symbols - this helps in lowering the number of duplicate symbols. I can get it down to 65 duplicate symbols until I have to remove GoogleUtilities.framework, which causes the build the fail with this error:

> Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
>   "_OBJC_CLASS_$_GULObjectSwizzler", referenced from:
>         objc-class-ref in FirebasePerformance(FPRObjectInstrumentor_f65d32035cadef24185912716f0b12f9.o)
>         objc-class-ref in FirebasePerformance(FPRNetworkTrace_3053ec2ab59f2fcfec4b18c29e4b4cec.o)
>         objc-class-ref in FirebasePerformance(FPRNSURLConnectionInstrument_5611d225f62417fa73742554b6a45401.o)
>   ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64 clang: error: linker
>   command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

3). Deleting DerivedData folder - I get the same errors after doing this.

4). Removing and adding the iOS platform - Same errors.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, this problem arose when using phonegap-plugin-push and cordova-plugin-firebase-analytics together. I found the fix in this [issue thread](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-push/issues/1863).

Basically, go to your Project Navigator in Xcode, then 'Build Phases', expand 'Link Binary With Libraries', click '+' and Add 'libGoogleToolboxForMac.a' and 'libPodsYourProjectName.a' and redo the build.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the reply - where do I find the libGoogleToolboxForMac.a file? I already have the one with my project name in it.

Comment: Try removing the platform and the plugins folder `ionic cordova platform rm ios` `rm -rf plugins`, then removing the Firebase plugin from config.xml so that you can install it manually later. Then install the platform `ionic cordova platform add ios`, then the Firebase plugin `ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-firebase`. You may need to install the pods separately, i.e. `cd platform/ios` `pod install`.

Comment: This fixed the duplicate symbols error for me! However I am now receiving the Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_GULObjectSwizzler", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in ... " error as described above. Any idea how to fix it? I also still don't know where to find the libGoogleToolboxForMac.a file.

Comment: I was able to fix my Undefined Symbols error by adding the firebase performance Cordova plugin and adding pod 'Firebase/Performance' to my pod file. The app will now build but crash with *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '+[FIRApp registerAsConfigurable:]: unrecognized selector sent to class 0x1080bc178'. Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: I am not sure but it sounds like a Cocoapods issue. Try `pod setup` (from any directory) to make sure Cocoapods is up-to-date, then run `pod install` from `<project-root>/platform/ios`.